# Search as you type, by using 2 textbox's to search 1 column

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following:

- Customer Table with customer field in it
- Query exactly based on the customer table
- Form named `Form1`

In `Form1` there are two `TextBox`s, namely `TxtCustomer1` and `TxtCustomer2`.

In the `Query`, within the criteria of the customer field, i have the following code indicated below:

```
Like "*" & [forms]![Form1]![TxtCustomer1].[Text] & "*" And _
Like "*" & [forms]![Form1]![txtCustomer2].[Text] & "*"
```

I hope you can see where I am going with this. I have placed the Query in `Form1` as a subform, named `Sub1`

The 2 textboxes `TxtCustomer1` and `TxtCustomer2` have an `OnChange` event, which re-query's the `Sub1`.

Currently, the 2 `TextBox`s are operational and are able to filter the `Sub1` subform in `Form1`.

But here is the problem:

I am not able to filter this 1 column by using 2 `TextBox`s together, its filtering out separately. In other words, after filtering via `Sub1` using `TxtCustomer1` I start typing to filter with `TxtCustomer2` at which point it restarts the sorting in `Sub1` and starts from teh bigeing, and vice versa using `TextCustomer2` first.

Alright, now I have been able to sort one column with 2 `TextBox`s,BUT had to make 2 changes:

- change 1: using "After Update" event, instead of "on change" event
- change 2: using the same exact code which i'v posted above, but without the  [Text] Control property, which looks like what is indicated below.

  `Like "*" & [forms]![Form1]![TxtCustomer1] & "*" And _
  Like "*" & [forms]![Form1]![TxtCustomer2] & "*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have now works, but it is no longer "Search as you type" when using the `AfterUpdate` event.

The `.Text` property is only available when a control has the focus, but it is also the only property that returns the text while typing -- `.Value` doesn't return it until leaving the control.

So what I would do is this:

```
Private Sub TxtCustomer1_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    ' TxtCustomer1 is currently edited -> use its .Text property, and .Value for TxtCustomer2
    Call DoFilter(Me!TxtCustomer1.Text, Me!TxtCustomer2.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub TxtCustomer2_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    ' The other way around
    Call DoFilter(Me!TxtCustomer1.Value, Me!TxtCustomer2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub DoFilter(ByVal Cust1 As Variant, ByVal Cust2 As Variant)

    Dim S As String
    S = "Customer Like '*" & Cust1 & "*' And Customer Like '*" & Cust2 & "*'"
    ' etc.

End Sub
```

Comment: so how can i implement this in the form ? 2 textboxes
first textbox named TxtCustomer1
second textbox named TxtCustomer2 

what else how do i set it up in a form ?

Comment: It's all there in the answer. Implement both `Dirty` events, and in `DoFilter()` you build the filter string, and then apply it to your result list (the suform).

Answer (score -2):

Please see these links for some guidance as to how to do this.

http://allenbrowne.com/appfindasutype.html

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/autofill-form-microsoft-access-tim-miles

http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/Search-As-You-Type-Access.html

https://blogs.office.com/2012/05/03/using-a-combo-box-to-search-as-you-type/

Aside from a Form, I think a ComboBox is the easiest way to do AutoComplete.  See the link below for some ideas of how to get it setup and working.

https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/index.html